# How can I bring back Web Essentials CSS Output Window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

I am using `Visual Studio with Update 4` and `Web Essentials` extension for precompiling and minifying `LESS` code. When I started using this for first time the output window was there but mistakenly I detached the window and now I am not finding the option to bring it back as it was before. I have gone through TOOLS and SETTING and even the extension settings itself but still not finding the way to bring it back.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Tools -> Options -> Web Essentials -> LESS -> Editor - > Show preview window

[image: VS2012]
This is a screenshot from VS2012 But I just checked in VS2013 and its still there.